# In Pyramid Framework what is the difference between default Unencrypted Session Factory and setting cookies manually?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

I do not understand the difference between setting up a Unencrypted Session Factory in order to set cookies, as compared to using `request.response.set_cookie(..)` and `request.cookies[key]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UnencryptedCookieSessionFactory` manages *one* cookie, that is *signed*. This means that the client can read<sup>1</sup> what is in the cookie, but cannot *change* the values in the cookie.

If you set cookies directly using `response.set_cookie()`, the client can not only read the cookie, they can change the value of the cookie and you won't be able to detect that the contents have been tampered with.

Moreover, the `UnencryptedCookieSessionFactory` let's you store any python structure and it'll take care of encoding these to fit within the limitations of a cookie; you'd have to do the same work manually with `.set_cookie()`.

<sup>1 <sub>You'd have to base64-decode the cookie, then use the `pickle` module to decode the contents. Because the cookie is cryptographically signed, the usual security concerns that apply to `pickle` are mitigated.</sub></sup>

Comment: Hi @Martijn. Thank you for this answer. Just realised my "accept answer" has not been registered, sorry about that!